# Systemd service starts too early and doesn't work on automated restart

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, systemd

I need to manually fix my microphone source and volume via pactl every time I boot. Otherwise, they change randomly.

To do so, I made a script - mic.sh, which works exactly as intended when I run it by itself.

I'm trying to make it into a systemd service that starts on every boot instead of me having to do it manually.

Problem is that, (what I thought), the service starts too early and can't connect to pulseaudio.

So, I changed my service, to restart on failure for 5 times, in gaps of 30 seconds.

Even with the automated restart, it doesn't work. Which kind of makes me think it isn't the problem of it starting very early? Because, in the time I was waiting for the service to finish it's last restart (5th), I was able to run the script manually, and it worked.

````
[Unit]
Description=mic.sh
StartLimitIntervalSec=240
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
ExecStart=/home/rain/sh/mic.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


##############################


rain@pop-os:~$ sudo systemctl status micsh.service
● micsh.service - mic.sh
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/micsh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-07-25 23:40:11 IST; 17s ago
    Process: 1993 ExecStart=/home/rain/sh/mic.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1993 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 25 23:40:11 pop-os systemd[1]: micsh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 25 23:40:11 pop-os systemd[1]: micsh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.



rain@pop-os:~$ sudo systemctl status micsh.service
● micsh.service - mic.sh
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/micsh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-07-25 23:40:41 IST; 8s ago
    Process: 2130 ExecStart=/home/rain/sh/mic.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2130 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)



rain@pop-os:~$ sudo systemctl status micsh.service
● micsh.service - mic.sh
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/micsh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-07-25 23:42:11 IST; 1min 11s ago
    Process: 2238 ExecStart=/home/rain/sh/mic.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2238 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 25 23:42:11 pop-os systemd[1]: micsh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 25 23:42:11 pop-os systemd[1]: Stopped mic.sh.
Jul 25 23:42:11 pop-os systemd[1]: micsh.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 25 23:42:11 pop-os systemd[1]: micsh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 25 23:42:11 pop-os systemd[1]: Failed to start mic.sh.```
````

Comment: You want it to talk to the pulseaudio process running in your login session, not some system-wide process, right?

Answer (score 0):

SystemD happens at system startup time, before you have logged in.

You should put a `.desktop` file in `$HOME/.config/autostart`.